# MVC: Passing value from Controller to View for GoogleMap

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller

Have tried a few ways, using **ViewBag** or **ViewData**, the value just couldn't pass to the variable in my script (View). Did i do something wrong?

```
//works
alert('@(Model.Long)');
alert('@(Model.Lat)');

//don't work
var long = '@(Model.Long)';
var lat =  '@(Model.Lat)';
```

Script document:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function () {
                Initialize();
            });

            // Where all the fun happens
            function Initialize() {

                alert('@(Model.Long)');
                alert('@(Model.Lat)');
                var long = 1.3048843;
                var lat = 103.7783736;

                google.maps.visualRefresh = true;
                var SearchLatLn = new google.maps.LatLng(long, lat);

                var mapOptions = {
                    zoom: 16,
                    center: SearchLatLn,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.G_NORMAL_MAP
                };

                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: SearchLatLn,
                    map: map,

                });

                marker.setMap(map);

                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content:"Hello World!"
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                    infowindow.open(map,marker);
                });
            }
        </script>
```

Please assist to solve my issue, thanks.

Comment: Try removing the ' surrounding the @Model

Comment: only a blank google map is display :/

Comment: Please post generated page html source code (script part only relevant)

Comment: Two things I notice right away; You  have your long and lat switched. 'long'  is not a good name, change it into lng, since long is a type.

Comment: `var long = '@(Model.Long)';` works just fine (assuming its a `float` or `double`). What do you think is not working?